# iOS9 to iOS10 upgrade: my app is crashing immediately

Tags: ios, ios10

I was testing my app successfully on iOS 10 beta builds and everything went good.

However, when upgrading an iPad Air2 from 9.3.5 to 10.0.1 using the "software update" in settings, the app was failing to launch consistently, showing the following log lines:

```
MY-Prod(libsystem_trace.dylib)[305] <Notice>: bundleid: com.company.pearlios, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
MY-Prod(libsystem_trace.dylib)[305] <Notice>: subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
cfprefsd(CoreFoundation)[79] <Fault>: rejecting write of key ApplicationAccessibilityEnabled in { com.apple.Accessibility, mobile, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, no container, managed: 0 } from process 305 because setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
MY-Prod(CoreFoundation)[305] <Error>: Failed to write value for key ApplicationAccessibilityEnabled in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x1740fd700> (Domain: com.apple.Accessibility, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null)): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access, switching to read-only
MY-Prod(CoreFoundation)[305] <Notice>: -[AccessibilitySettingsController setAXInspectorEnabled:specifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a804600
MY-Prod(CoreFoundation)[305] <Notice>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AccessibilitySettingsController setAXInspectorEnabled:specifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a804600'
```

I would appreciate any help in understanding what is going on here!

Comment: I guess the crucial information is *setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access*

Comment: Do you have EarlGray embedded in your app?

Comment: No sorry. And I can't reproduce it anymore because already deleted the old app and re-installed.